VRF local testing issues,Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with custom error 'InsufficientBalance()'
Currently I am on Lesson: 9 of PatrickCollins Course, and I directly upgraded to use VRF V2_5. Use Hardhat
I passed 13 of my 14 tests, but the last one showed that I didn't have enough funds.
In the following code, I have checked my funds and the display is very strange(The code has omitted parts)
Raffle.test.js
describe("fulfillRandomWords", function () {
              let raffleAddress, vrfCoordinatorV2MockAddress

              beforeEach(async function () {
                  await raffle.enterRaffle({ value: raffleEntranceFee })
                  await network.provider.send("evm_increaseTime", [Number(interval) + 1])
                  await network.provider.request({ method: "evm_mine", params: [] })
                  raffleAddress = await raffle.getAddress()
                  vrfCoordinatorV2MockAddress = await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.getAddress()
              })
              it("can only be called after performupkeep", async function () {
                  await expect(
                      vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.fulfillRandomWords(0, raffleAddress),
                  ).to.be.revertedWithCustomError(vrfCoordinatorV2Mock, "InvalidRequest")
                  await expect(
                      vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.fulfillRandomWords(1, raffleAddress),
                  ).to.be.revertedWithCustomError(vrfCoordinatorV2Mock, "InvalidRequest")
              })

              //Integration Test
              it("picks a winner, resets, and sends money", async function () {
                  // Ensure the subscription is funded
                  subscriptionId = await raffle.getSubscriptionId() // Ensure you get the subscriptionId from the Raffle contract
                  const subscriptionInfo =
                      await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.getSubscription(subscriptionId)
                  console.log(
                      `Subscription ID: ${subscriptionId} has a balance of ${subscriptionInfo.balance.toString()} WEI`,
                  )
                  console.log("-------------------------------------------------------------")
                  const additionalEntrances = 3 // to test
                  const startingIndex = 2
                  const accounts = await ethers.getSigners()
                  for (let i = startingIndex; i < startingIndex + additionalEntrances; i++) {
                      const accountConnectedRaffle = raffle.connect(accounts[i])
                      await accountConnectedRaffle.enterRaffle({ value: raffleEntranceFee })
                  }
                  const startingTimeStamp = await raffle.getLastTimeStamp()

                  console.log("Starting performUpkeep...")

                  const tx = await raffle.performUpkeep("0x")
                  const txReceipt = await tx.wait(1)

                  const requestId = txReceipt.logs[1].args.requestId

                  let vrfCoordinatorBalance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(
                      vrfCoordinatorV2MockAddress,
                  )
                  console.log("VRFCoordinator Balance:", vrfCoordinatorBalance.toString()) 

                  await new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
                      raffle.once("WinnerPicked", async function () {
                          //   console.log("Found the event!!!")
                          try {
                              const recentWinner = await raffle.getRecentWinner()
                              console.log("Recent winner:", recentWinner)
                              const raffleState = await raffle.getRaffleState()
                              const endingTimeStamp = await raffle.getLastTimeStamp()
                              const numPlayers = await raffle.getNumberOfPlayers()
                              assert.equal(numPlayers.toString(), "0")
                              assert.equal(raffleState.toString(), "0")
                              assert(endingTimeStamp > startingTimeStamp)
                              resolve() 
                          } catch (e) {
                              reject(e) 
                          }
                      })

                      try {
                          //   console.log("Starting fulfillRandomWords...")
                          await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.fulfillRandomWords(requestId, raffleAddress)
                          //   console.log("fulfillRandomWords done.")
                      } catch (e) {
                          reject(e) // 捕获错误时调用 reject
                      }
                  })
              })
          })

run yarn hardhat test --grep .... 
Subscription ID: 54833296975178399311052914149901609787461517173670223479185380064579138314792 has a balance of 2000000000000000000 WEI
-------------------------------------------------------------
Starting performUpkeep...
VRFCoordinator Balance: 0
      1) picks a winner, resets, and sends money


  13 passing (2s)
  1 failing

  1) Raffle Unit Tests
       fulfillRandomWords
         picks a winner, resets, and sends money:
     Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with custom error 'InsufficientBalance()'

01-deploy-raffle.js
const { network, ethers } = require("hardhat")
const {
    networkConfig,
    developmentChains,
    VERIFICATION_BLOCK_CONFIRMATIONS,
} = require("../helper-hardhat-config")
const { verify } = require("../utils/verify")

const FUND_AMOUNT = "2000000000000000000" // 2 ETH

module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {
    const { deploy, log } = deployments
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
    const chainId = network.config.chainId
    let vrfCoordinatorV2Address, subscriptionId, vrfCoordinatorV2Mock

    if (chainId == 31337) {
        vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContract("VRFCoordinatorV2_5Mock")
        vrfCoordinatorV2Address = await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.getAddress()

        const transactionResponse = await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.createSubscription()
        const transactionReceipt = await transactionResponse.wait(1)

        subscriptionId = transactionReceipt.logs[0].args.subId.toString()

        await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.fundSubscription(subscriptionId, FUND_AMOUNT)
        log("-------------------------------------------------------------")
        log(`Funded subscription with ID: ${subscriptionId} with ${FUND_AMOUNT.toString()} WEI`)

        const subscriptionInfo = await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.getSubscription(subscriptionId)
        log(
            `Subscription ID: ${subscriptionId} has a balance of ${subscriptionInfo.balance.toString()} WEI`,
        )
        log("-------------------------------------------------------------")
    } else {
        vrfCoordinatorV2Address = networkConfig[chainId]["vrfCoordinatorV2"]
        subscriptionId = networkConfig[chainId]["subscriptionId"]
    }

    const waitBlockConfirmations = developmentChains.includes(network.name)
        ? 1
        : VERIFICATION_BLOCK_CONFIRMATIONS

    const args = [
        vrfCoordinatorV2Address,
        subscriptionId,
        networkConfig[chainId]["gasLane"],
        networkConfig[chainId]["keepersUpdateInterval"],
        networkConfig[chainId]["raffleEntranceFee"],
        networkConfig[chainId]["callbackGasLimit"],
    ]
    const raffle = await deploy("Raffle", {
        from: deployer,
        args: args,
        log: true,
        waitConfirmations: waitBlockConfirmations,
    })

    if (developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {
        await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.addConsumer(subscriptionId, raffle.address)
    }

    if (!developmentChains.includes(network.name) && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY) {
        log("Verifying...")
        await verify(raffle.address, args)
    }

    log("Enter lottery with command:")
    const networkName = network.name == "hardhat" ? "localhost" : network.name
    log(`yarn hardhat run scripts/enterRaffle.js --network ${networkName}`)
    log("----------------------------------------------------")
}

module.exports.tags = ["all", "raffle"]

run yarn hardhat deploy
Nothing to compile
Local network detected! Deploying mocks...
deploying "VRFCoordinatorV2_5Mock" (tx: 0x148fccd4245c8af8076ba828c4cd9e7a9f4a68be7d5d731d0e4f4f1a30b91dee)...: deployed at 0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d9
3F642f64180aa3 with 5369612 gas                                                                                                                         -------------------------------------------------------------
Funded subscription with ID: 93320521801340531155697145994410935527471159147619150892782246375313326801390 with 2000000000000000000 WEI
Subscription ID: 93320521801340531155697145994410935527471159147619150892782246375313326801390 has a balance of 2000000000000000000 WEI
-------------------------------------------------------------
deploying "Raffle" (tx: 0x287945ceef135b6123d5136f09597d65d8b211cb74f78f93c14f237613454e76)...: deployed at 0xCf7Ed3AccA5a467e9e704C703E8D87F634fB0Fc9 w
ith 1863368 gas                                                                                                                                         Enter lottery with command:
yarn hardhat run scripts/enterRaffle.js --network localhost
----------------------------------------------------

Many thanks for your help

In the performUpkeep() function of your Lottery contract, while calling the requestRandomWords() function, have you declared the nativePayment field in the extraArgs as true or false?

@ SYED ASAD KAZMI is false.
extraArgs: VRFV2PlusClient._argsToBytes(
                VRFV2PlusClient.ExtraArgsV1({nativePayment: false}) //use ETH to test
            )


As, you’ve mentioned in the comments that nativePayment is set to false in the extraArgs of the requestRandomWords() function call, so it’s expecting the amount to be funded in the subscription in the form of LINK tokens instead of ether (i.e., native tokens).
But, the balance that you’re logging is ether (i.e., native token) balance:
let vrfCoordinatorBalance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(vrfCoordinatorV2MockAddress)
console.log("VRFCoordinator Balance:", vrfCoordinatorBalance.toString()) 

And, you’re funding the subscription with mock LINK tokens (not native tokens), that’s why it’s logging the balance as 0.
Everything is fine, but the amount that you’re funding is 2 mock LINK tokens which is quite less, because as far as I’ve experienced by debugging, it’s expecting slightly higher amount possibly around 60-70 tokens. So, hopefully by changing the amount to 100 would solve the InsufficientBalance() error that you’re getting.
So, just replace this line in your 01-deploy-raffle.js file:
const FUND_AMOUNT = "2000000000000000000"

with:
const FUND_AMOUNT = "100000000000000000000"

And, run your test again.

Thank you again ! @SYED ASAD KAZMI

You’re welcome, @Taufik. Happy coding!
